How to import a library module with aliased plugins and dependencies into new AndroidStudio projects
The latests gradle plugins and Android Studio versions recommend the use of aliases for plugins and dependencies.
I created a library by doing:

New Project
then New Module (Android Library)

So general question is: Since everything is made to be project-centric, how can I later import my library module into a new project (which is the goal of a library) ? As far as I know, only the :module folder is imported...
The detailed list of my struggles is below

Dependency declaration: I need to declare them, but need to comment out this line from gradle.settings to do it the old way:

   repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)


aliases: all the aliases are stored in a project-level toml file, so again, not imported in my new project in Android Studio if I import this module!

Example at first line of module-level gradle:
No such property: library for class: org.gradle.accessors.dm.LibrariesForLibs$AndroidPluginAccessors
So I'm confused. Have I missed the point of project-centric things? My goal was to sync the module library using remote git repos between different android applications, but still be able to edit the source from each project, since it's not production level.
Do I have to compile an .aar everytime instead?

"how can I later import my library module into a new project (which is the goal of a library) ?" -- I recommend publishing the library to a Maven repository (Maven Local if it's just you, or some Maven repository in a central spot for your team). That will contain the transitive dependency information about what libraries your library needs. Your projects that consume your library would then just need to reference that library, and the rest will be handled by Gradle.

"My goal was to sync the module library using remote git repos between different android applications" -- if you mean git sub-modules, I was part of an engineering organization that tried using them for this sort of role. We hated it; if we were to do it over again, we would use a Maven repository as described above. "but still be able to edit the source from each project, since it's not production level" -- I am unclear what "production level" has to do with having more than one IDE window open.

Thanks for the comments. I actually made myself the same one regarding IDE windows. That said, it would mean having to produce a "fat-jar", right? otherwise, I have to reinclude everything in the new project, right?

"it would mean having to produce a "fat-jar", right?" -- not if you publish the library to a Maven repository. The POM file that will go alongside your JAR/AAR will document the dependencies that your JAR/AAR needs. When you reference your library from another project, Gradle uses that POM to determine what else needs to be downloaded. Most of the libraries that you depend on right now have POM files that list a bunch of other libraries that they in turn use -- you would leverage the same system.

Ok, you're right, I guess as often, the struggle comes from asking the wrong question. I spent yesterday on making a gradle task that injects buildconfigfields to both the library and the app. At the end, I'm still not decided whether what I want is a library, an app template,(or else?). I realized I should also dig into Proxy since in the "library", my buildConfig fields are mainly used in wrapper functions...

So far, I ended up making a library, published to localMaven, with plenty of new interfaces, that forces the implementation of buildconfig getters when extending some class. Time will tell me whether it's smart or not.
